# how to set logo and text for my web site to share on facebook on any social media?

Tags: html, facebook, tags, share

How to set logo and text for my web site to share on facebook? 
I have set

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url"/>
```

and

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site_name"/>
```

but it not work. please help

Comment: Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, and click the “fetch new scrape information” button to make Facebook clear its cache. If there’s any error messages/warnings, fix them.

Answer (score 1):

basics of Opengraph meta tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MyPage</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of Page/Post" />
<meta property="og:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="My site link" />
<meta property="og:image" content="img link" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Here is some more properties of OG's example for custom sizing with default values

```
   <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
   <meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
   <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

source: [opg.me](http://ogp.me/)

Comment: thank you for your response. but i still have problem. google+ and linkedin shows correctly but facebook still shows old logo(I used different logo before). is it cache problem or something like this?

Comment: Yes, it's more looks like cache problems.

Comment: I used ctrl + f5. also deleted all browser cache but still same result. also used different browser still same result. strange

Answer (score 1):

simply copy this below and it should work and change when you change the text, I also added what you need to be able to do this on twitter too.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Lewis Derbyshire" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lewis Derbyshire's description" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.lewisderbyshire.co.uk/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Lewis Derbyshire" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.lewisderbyshire.co.uk/image.jpg" />

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Derbyshire10" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Derbyshire10" />
<meta property="og:url" content="Https://LewisDerbyshire.co.uk" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Lewis Derbyshire" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lewis Derbyshire's Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://LewisDerbyshire.co.uk/image.jpg" />
```

Hope it Helps, Lewis